# How to get authenticated in Microsoft teams tab in python

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

The login page is displaying in the team's tab on the browser. Now the issue is on the login prompt it tries to open iframe which is not allowed in the one another iframe in the team's tab. It works fine on a normal browser page but having an issue only in the team's tab on the browser.

The error which we are getting is like: Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Details of Code:
Language: Python
Architecture: Flask Apis for rendering pages
Issue: iframe not working in team's browser tab.
Authentication: MSGraph.Authorization

Could you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using MSAL 2.0 (recommended). If so, there are two auth flows - redirect and popup. In Teams, it's a little different because Teams itself is actually launching the popup for the auth flow. As a result, even though it **involves** a popup, this popup will launch to your own auth page, and you end up doing **redirect** flow from inside there.

Here's a sample I put together for Tab SSO that should help (it's not python, but hopefully the node/Dotnet examples will be good enough guidance): https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso

Comment: Hi @maheshpardeshi - please let us know if your issue has been resolved.